# Linux native config file format read efficiency

Tags: linux, performance, qt, configuration-files

Is there a common practice on reading linux config files in a native format efficiently? Files are handled as streams, hence I guess the standard way to lookup by parsing is in O(n*m) (Let n lines, m avg line length).
Is it common practice to build search trees from config files, or has this already been implemented, by e.g. QSettings?

Comment: On Linux systems (and POSIX systems in general) there is *no* native or common configuration file. And as configuration files typically are read once (at program start) the need for efficiency is rather small. Instead the requirements most often are that the files should be readable and modifiable by human beings, in other words simple text formats.

Comment: Sorry, I meant INI format. For Qt this is the same but the extension. (native/*.conf, INI/*.ini)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this a problem? QSettings usually has very few kb of data, which can be loaded and parsed in a fraction of time. You don't really need to care about it. Reading `kb`s in a desktop is something which cannot be measured.

The recommendation is usually to create a QSettings object when needed (in stack) and use it to read when needed. This is what I see in some Qt applications. The Qt documentation mentions this is light weight. I usually maintain a global variable in my QMainWindow.